# Can I ask subversion to "merge my latest change from a given branch"

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I don't want to merge the HEAD revision in case somebody else has made a commit just after I have to the branch I'm merging from. So I want to enter something like "head:noelicus" in the "revision range to merge" box.
At the moment I'm (using Tortoise and) clicking on "Show Log" to find my latest change in the branch I'm merging from.

Comment: I don't get it yet. Do you want to merge only your changes, not the ones of others? Why is it not possible to just use the revision numbers of your changes?

Comment: Because it's quicker, easier, simpler, and pretty much the only reason I ever merge (always my latest change from a given branch). Yes I want to merge my change and not the ones of others.